# Config nginx.conf so that .html extensions aren't displayed

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm new to nginx configuration so not sure how to go about this, but any help would be appreciated.

I have a company.com/jobs.html page set up, but would like to point the URL company.com/jobs to the content of company.com/jobs.html while keeping the URL as company.com/jobs

This is what I changed in my nginx.conf file:

```
location / {
rewrite ^/jobs$ jobs.html last;
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm running into some trouble and not sure what to try next. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ ^/jobs$ {
    try_files $uri.html $uri;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your post? Here at Stack Overflow, we tend to treat answers with more than just code better than code-only ones.